# Recover the R.java file

Tags: android, r.java-file

While compiling my project, I lost my R.java file.

I recreated the new project and replaced all my .xml files, .java files, and all my images in the project, but in that project I also lost my R.java file.

What should do to solve this problem? Can I recreate my R.java file for the project?

Comment: just clean and build the project

Comment: Are you using eclipse by the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The R.java file is automatically generated by the Android tools ; so, you should always be able to re-generate it.

In this kind of case, forcing a clean and full-rebuild of the project generally helps.

In Eclipse, try :

- Project > Clean
- And choose to clean your project.

Comment: i cleaned the project but same result with out creating the R.java

Comment: Are you sure there is no error in your XML files, that would prevent the R.java file from being re-created ? *(as it's constructed from the XML files)*

Comment: Told you that was the problem. ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy all the src files to a backup folder.
2. clean and build the project.
3. You will get the R file.
4. Then copy back the files back to src

Answer (score 2):

There might be 2 possibilities:

1. There might be any error in one of XML files.
2. Just clean and build your project again.

Comment: i cleaned but i didn't get R.java file

Comment: ok.. just check your all XML file. because there may be a small error.

Comment: do you have properly imported android.R?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and it came down to having a resource file named 'case.xml'. It seems that 'case' is a reseved identifier. I just changed the name and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Usually "losing" your R.java file happens when you have an error in your XML. The same for the resources.ap_ FileNotFound issue.

Try to have a look in the error list and see if you have any errors in your XML files. Fix them and then re-build as mentioned above.

Comment: i m trying to create the new project the when i clean the project then R.java deleted

Answer (score 0):

If you try all the above answer and you still getting the error then check your java file.
If there is any import `android.R` file then remove that sentense.
again try cleaning and building you project.
I hope this will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you `clean project` while your .xml file contains an error then it will remove your auto generated `R.java` file, so don't clean your project while any of your .xml files contain an error.