# Unable to Recover R.java file

Tags: java, android

I am learning android and unfortunately my R.java file has been deleted.

So how can i recover it.

**I already tried to CLEAN the project.**

But When i do this all the files in the Gen folders are generated again except R.java.

What can be the solution?

I already read the following links.

[R.java file gets deleted suddenly on cleaning project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244790/r-java-file-gets-deleted-suddenly-on-cleaning-project)

[Recover the R.java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259661/recover-the-r-java-file)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ESWnmPFoc68

Comment: Did you also rebuild the project?  Cleaning is but one step.

Comment: @Makoto yes.... i already tried...

Comment: look in your classes for the import android.R; if its in them delete it then clean and build

Comment: make sure that there is no conflict with your xml layout or images. like the naming. because if you have a problem like that R.Java will not generated.

Comment: Check if you've got a typo in an xml file or something. in Eclipse open the Problems tab in the console. R.java wont be generated if there's a syntax error (using - instead of _ in XMl)

Comment: What is the last thing you did before you noticed it was missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most times, when the R file isn't being generated, it's due to a problem with something in your res folder.

Here's what you should do:

1. Go over all your layout files, make sure the XML syntax is good, and there are no problems there
2. Go over all your file names in drawables, layout, etc. Make sure that the file names are all lower case, and no illegal chars exist there.

Sometimes your console output will give you clues if there's a problem in your res folder.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I already checked all the layouts as well as all the drawable folder.

Comment: In my problems tab there is only one type of issue and it is related to R.java "R cannot to be resolved a variable".